# Qt get file path of current playing media?

Tags: qt, qmediaplayer

I need to store the full path of current playing audio in `QMediaPlayer` in a `QString` Variable. I need this to get metadata using `taglib` library which require file path of the media.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediacontent.html#canonicalUrl).

You can do it by calling

```
mediaplayer.currentMedia().canonicalUrl().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#media-prop,
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediacontent.html#resources,
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaresource.html#url and
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#path
you can use `mediaPlayer->media.resources.first().url().path()`.